# Journey Builder for Apps Android SDK with firebase

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush

I'm new to Android development and I'm trying hard to develop an app to get a push from salesforce marketingcloud.

I've tried to follow some of this [LearningAppAndroid](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/LearningAppAndroid) procedures. But without result. It gives several debug errors and does not receive the push message.

I tried following the steps outlined on the [getting started page](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/overview/getting-started.html).

But it seems to give many errors in the gradle after putting the:

> Compile ('com.salesforce.marketingcloud: marketingcloudsdk: 5.0. +') {         Exclude module: 'android-beacon-library' // remove to use Proximity messaging         Exclude module: 'play-services-location' // remove to use Geofence or Proximity messaging     }

I check the errors using the command "-q dependencies app: dependencies --configuration compile"

It seems to me that Journey Builder does not have the documentation up to date.

Has anyone managed to use Journey Builder with firebase in version 11.0.2 (firebase)?

Could someone give a simple example with the current libs?

Comment: Can you please provide the error(s) you're experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Version 5.0.x of the SDK requires a `Legacy GCM Token` from Google.  The steps to attain the correct token are noted in the documentation [HERE](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/provisioning/google.html).

A future release of the SDK will transition the Marketing Cloud Servers and the SDK to FCM, but rest assured that all push functionality will work in the interim.

Also, version 5.0.x is dependent on Google Play Services version 10.2.4 as noted in the [RELEASE NOTES](http://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/JB4A-SDK-Android/).  You cannot mix-and-match Google Play Services' component versions.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much, Bill.
It was a detail that made all the difference.
I put Google Play Services version 10.2.4 and everything worked perfectly.

Thanks for the quick return.